# SwiftUI: Event is not triggering in Tabview for image scrolling

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I am trying to scroll the image in tabbar, but i am unable to get the onchange when the image is scrolled.

```
@State private var currentIndex = 0

TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
                ForEach(model, id: \.self) { detail in
                        Image(uiImage: detail.image)
                            .resizable()
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                            .frame(width: 100,height: 100,alignment: .center)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: currentIndex) { _ in
                print("*********")
                print(currentIndex)
                
            }
```

> XCode Version: 15.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change to

`ForEach(0..<model.count) { i in`

the complete code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var currentIndex = 0
  @State private var model: [Model] = []
  
  var body: some View {
    if model != [] {
      TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
        ForEach(0..<model.count) { i in
          Image(uiImage: model[i].image)
            .resizable()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .frame(width: 100,height: 100,alignment: .center)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        }
      }
      .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
      .onChange(of: currentIndex) { _ in
        print("*********")
        print(currentIndex)
        
      }
    } else {
      Color.clear
        .onAppear {
          for _ in 0..<10 {
            model.append(Model(image: UIImage(named: "test")!))
          }
        }
    }
  }
}

struct Model: Equatable, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var image: UIImage
}
```